# Must pthread_create() and pthread_join() called in main function?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am new to multi-threading in C. I looked some online example and found that pthread_create() and pthread_join() are always called in the main function. 
for exmaple:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define NTHREADS 10
void *thread_function(void *);
main()
{
   pthread_t thread_id[NTHREADS];
   int i, j;

   for(i=0; i < NTHREADS; i++)
   {
      pthread_create( &thread_id[i], NULL, thread_function, NULL );
   }

   for(j=0; j < NTHREADS; j++)
   {
      pthread_join( thread_id[j], NULL); 
   }

}
```

My question is, is it possible to call pthread_create() and pthread_join() in other functions other than the main function? I also saw examples where there is a '&' in front of the thread_function, is it necessary? If it is, why?

Comment: Using `thread_function` and `&thread_function` is equivalent here.

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely, you can call these functions from other functions. The reason why most online examples show these functions called from `main` is that they try to get their examples shorter and easier to understand.

More importantly, however, is that `pthread_create` and `pthread_join` calls can be made from other threads, not just from other functions running on the main thread. It is perfectly legal for threads other than the main one to start other threads, and to wait for their completion. As long as thread handle is valid and accessible, your threads can wait for each others' completion, and create new threads as needed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can call them in other functions as well.

Comment: I couldn't find any examples online, can you explain why they are always called in the main function?

Comment: `main()`, just like other functions, represent a logical unit in a program. I personally like my `main()` function to call the a thread creating function, but it's up to you.
 For example, this is the function call in `main()`: `initThreadsArray(tp,C_lock); // this function initializes threads using pthread_create`

Comment: Thanks! Another question, when call pthread_create(), do I have to add a '&' in front of the thread_function?

Comment: I didn't understand the question, and maybe you should post a new question instead of asking it here on comments, will make it easier.

Comment: I mean, is pthread_create( &thread_id[i], NULL, &thread_function, NULL ) also valid? @galfisher

Comment: That's the only valid way, since `pthread_create()` third parameter is of type pointer to function

Comment: But the example I provided above is different, is it wrong? @galfisher

Comment: I think both will work, i don't want to confuse you though cause I am not 100% sure on this. [You can read this for further reference](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/134721-how-call-function-function-pointer.html#post1003003).